Trying to replicate pure CSS stacking cards with react tsx, not sure how to proceed
I'm trying to recreate a component I've mad ein pure css in a react tsx component, but im not sure how to proceed.
Here is the html/css that does exaclty what I want.
<body>
    <div class="left-content">
        <h1>Headings</h1>
        <p>This section contains the headings and occupies the left 50% of the screen.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="cards">
            <li class="card" id="card1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Card 1</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Card 2</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Card 3</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="card" id="card4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Card 4</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
</body>

css:
body {
            background-color: #2E3537;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        :root {
            --cards: 5;
            --cardHeight: 87vh;
            --cardTopPadding: 0em;
            --cardMargin: 4vw;
        }

        .container {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
        }

        #cards {
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--cards), var(--cardHeight));
            gap: var(--cardMargin);
            padding-bottom: calc(var(--cards) * var(--cardTopPadding));
            margin-bottom: var(--cardMargin);
        }

        .card {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            padding-top: calc(var(--index) * var(--cardTopPadding));
        }

        #card1 .card-body {
            background-color: #52B2CF;
        }
        #card2 .card-body {
            background-color: #E5A36F;
        }
        #card3 .card-body {
            background-color: #9CADCE;
        }
        #card4 .card-body {
            background-color: #D4AFB9;
        }

        .card-body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 30px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            height: var(--cardHeight);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 8em;
        }

        .left-content {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
            color: white;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          position:fixed;
        }

        .left-content h1 {
            font-size: 3em;
        }

        .left-content p {
            font-size: 1.5em;
}

and this is my attaempt at a reatc tsx component:

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import placeholderImage from './placeholder.png'; // Assume you have a placeholder image
import './ThirdSection.css';

const BigRow = styled('div')({
    backgroundColor: '#00E186',
    color: 'white',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: '0',
    margin: '0',
    overflow: 'hidden',
});

const TextSection = styled('div')({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: '1',
    width: '100%',
    paddingTop: '60px', // Adjust padding to account for the fixed navbar
    padding: '0',
    margin: '0',
    position: 'relative',
});

const StackedCardsContainer = styled('div')({
    flex: '1 1 60%',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '100vh',
    // overflow: 'hidden',
    margin: '20px',
    position: 'relative',
});

const Image = styled(motion.img)({
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    objectFit: 'cover',
});

const TextContainer = styled('div')({
    flex: '40%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '100vh',
    padding: '2rem',
    textAlign: 'center',
});

const AnimatedText = styled(motion.h1)({
    fontSize: '5rem',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
});

const HorizontalLine = styled('hr')({
    width: '100%',
    borderTop: '1px solid white',
    margin: '2rem 0', 

});

const AnimatedH5 = styled('h5')({
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    margin: '0rem 0',
});

const ThirdSection: React.FC = () => {
    const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState('');
    const text = '  Subheading goes here.';
    const controls = useAnimation();
    const [ref, inView] = useInView({
        threshold: 0.2,
        triggerOnce: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView) {
            controls.start('visible');
        }
    }, [controls, inView]);

    const textVariants = {
        hidden: { opacity: 0, y: 20 },
        visible: { opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 2 } },
    };

 

    useEffect(() => {
        let index = 0;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setDisplayText((prev) => {
                if (index < text.length) {
                    return prev + text[index];
                }
                clearInterval(interval);
                return prev;
            });
            index++;
        }, 2);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [text]);

    return (
        <BigRow ref={ref}>
            <TextSection>
                <TextContainer>
                    <AnimatedText
                        variants={textVariants}
                        initial="hidden"
                        animate={controls}
                    >
                        Big heading here
                    </AnimatedText>
                    <HorizontalLine />
                    <AnimatedH5>{displayText}</AnimatedH5>
                </TextContainer>
                <StackedCardsContainer>
                    <div className="container">
                        <ul id="cards">
                            <li className="card" id="card1">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 1</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="card" id="card2">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 2</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="card" id="card3">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 3</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="card" id="card4">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 4</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </StackedCardsContainer>
            </TextSection>
        </BigRow>

    );
};

export default ThirdSection;


Where ThirdSection.css is the same stylesheet as before.
The main issue is that overflow:hidden is required for the bigrow parent, sinc otherwise the cards overflow ino the parent, but have overflow:hidden breaks the animation.
The partial solution is having overflow:scroll for the StackCardsContainer, but that doesn't look very good, as you have 2 scrolling bars, and also the textSection is then not fixed.
Any suggestions on how I  can fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've changed the code a bit to work the way the html one is working. Hope it helps.
Edited:
tsx:
const BigRow = styled('div')({
    height:'100%',
    backgroundColor: '#00E186',
    color: 'white',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: '0',
    margin: '0',
    overflow: 'hidden',
});

const TextSection = styled('div')({
    overflow: 'auto',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
});

const StackedCardsContainer = styled('div')({
    flex: '1 1 60%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    height:'100%'
});

const Image = styled(motion.img)({
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    objectFit: 'cover',
});

const TextContainer = styled('div')({
    flex: '40%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: '2rem',
    textAlign: 'center',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '50%',
    left: '0',
    transform:'translate(0, -50%)',
    pointerEvents:"none",
});

const AnimatedText = styled(motion.h1)({
    fontSize: '5rem',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
});

const HorizontalLine = styled('hr')({
    width: '100%',
    borderTop: '1px solid white',
    margin: '2rem 0',

});

const AnimatedH5 = styled('h5')({
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    margin: '0rem 0',
});

export const ThirdSection: React.FC = () => {
    const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState('');
    const text = '  Subheading goes here.';
    const controls = useAnimation();
    const [ref, inView] = useInView({
        threshold: 0.2,
        triggerOnce: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView) {
            controls.start('visible');
        }
    }, [controls, inView]);

    const textVariants = {
        hidden: { opacity: 0, y: 20 },
        visible: { opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 2 } },
    };



    useEffect(() => {
        let index = 0;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setDisplayText((prev) => {
                if (index < text.length) {
                    return prev + text[index];
                }
                clearInterval(interval);
                return prev;
            });
            index++;
        }, 2);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [text]);

    return (
        <BigRow ref={ref}>
            <TextSection>
                <TextContainer>
                    <AnimatedText
                        variants={textVariants}
                        initial="hidden"
                        animate={controls}
                    >
                        Big heading here
                    </AnimatedText>
                    <HorizontalLine />
                    <AnimatedH5>{displayText}</AnimatedH5>
                </TextContainer>
                <StackedCardsContainer>
                    <div className="container">
                        <ul id="cards">
                            <li className="card" id="card1">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 1</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="card" id="card2">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 2</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="card" id="card3">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 3</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="card" id="card4">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h2>Card 4</h2>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </StackedCardsContainer>
            </TextSection>
        </BigRow>

    );
};

css:
html,body,#root,.App{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #2E3537;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --cards: 5;
    --cardHeight: 87vh;
    --cardTopPadding: 0em;
    --cardMargin: 4vw;
}

.container {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
}

#cards {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--cards), var(--cardHeight));
    gap: var(--cardMargin);
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--cards) * var(--cardTopPadding));
    margin-bottom: var(--cardMargin);
}

.card {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: calc(var(--index) * var(--cardTopPadding));
}

#card1 .card-body {
    background-color: #52B2CF;
}
#card2 .card-body {
    background-color: #E5A36F;
}
#card3 .card-body {
    background-color: #9CADCE;
}
#card4 .card-body {
    background-color: #D4AFB9;
}

.card-body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: var(--cardHeight);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 8em;
}

.left-content {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:fixed;
}

.left-content h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.left-content p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}



Thank you! I really appreciate this. There are a couple of things I'd like to chnage and not sure how to.
Firstly, the stacked cards are still a separate scroll, as opposed to the primary scroll, I don't know how to fix that.
And secondly, depending on where the user has the cursor, the cards might start stacking before this component is fully in view. Is there anyway to mitigate this?
Thank you again for all your help!

Edited the above to fix the issues mentioned. Hope it helps to unblock you thus you would be able to carry out any necessary improvements

Thank you again for your answer!
In isolation it works great, exactly what I wanted, so thank you.
However, when having this component nested within another "page" component, the tiles are invisible, and the left text container overlaps over all the previous stuff in the page, as opposed to being "contained" within the component itself. How can i ensure this code you provided me works, within a larger page, as an individual section of the page?
Thank you again for all your help!

Well, you need all the requirements when developing (at least all that you know at that specific point in time). Thus without knowing the bigger picture its going to be difficult to have a generic component that you would be able to inject anywhere and expect it to work especially with the behaviour described in the question. One way to go forward is to separate the component have the cards on their own component and their behaviour and continue by developing part by part. The answer provided helps you on how to move forward, which is exactly the point of the forum.

Having said the above unfortunately I won't be able to continue adding code or fixing parts to delivered a polished solution. The above unblocks you thus with some more research, trial and error I believe you will get the desired result :)

Thank you for your help! I think I’ll try making the css attributes conditional on the scrolling so that they only bahrv like I want them to once fully on the screen. Thank you again for all your help.
